# JavaScript - Is it okay to define a property of a previously declared object during a variable declaration?

Tags: javascript, object, properties, variable-declaration

Is it common practice (or at least syntactically valid across browsers and implementations of JS) to abuse RTL associativity of assignment operators so that one can define two variables (with the first being an object) so that the second is assigned to a (newly) named property of that object which is itself assigned to another value, so that a SyntaxError() is not generated?

I know that sounds complicated, but here is the code:

```
var x = {}, y = x.l = 9; // generates no errors
console.log(x.l, y); // 9 9
```

Since:

```
var t = {}, t.l = 9; // Syntax Error, no doubt because t is already defined
```

Comment: Change the comma to a semi colon and read up on how the [*comma operator*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) works in javascript

Comment: that makes no sense. If you are creating an object literal and you know a property will exist, do it in the original assignment: `var t = { l: 9 };`

Comment: The number of letters: `var x = {}, y = x.l = x.k = x.z = null` as opposed to `var x = {l : null, k: null, z: null}, y = x.l`. Granted it's not a huge difference but when writing complicated code it can be helpful to know whether the former approach is valid JS.

Comment: The code in the comment is fine but is also different than the code that has the syntax error.  Again, read up on how comma operator works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line:

```
var x = {}, y = x.l = 9;
```

effectively becomes:

```
var x = {};
var y = x.l = 9;
```

which is processed as:

```
// Parse phase
var x; // assigned the value undefined
var y; // assigned the value undefined

// Execution phase
x = {};
x.l = 9;
y = x.l;
```

Noting that in an assignment expression, the value on the right is assigned to the expression on the left. Compound assignments are *evaluated* left to right, but *assigned* from right to left, hence `x.l = 9` is assigned before `y = x.l`, even though it's on the right.

Now try that with the second example:

```
var t = {}, t.l = 9;
```

becomes:

```
// Parse phase
var t;   // assigned the value undefined
var t.l; // syntax error, stop
```

The *var* keyword at the start of a statement means the next thing must be a valid identifier. `t.l` is not a valid identifier (it can only be interpreted as an identifier followed by a dot property accessor), so that's it. Everything stops.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the semicolon - that's what the error says the parser expects:

```js
var t = {}; 
t.l = 9;
console.log(t);
```

Comment: This still makes absolutely no sense as written.

Comment: What do you mean @RandyCasburn?

Comment: If the OP knows the property and the value writing the object literal as a single assignment is the proper way to approach this.

Comment: @RandyCasburn—it's just an example, the question is more about why one case returns a syntax error and the other doesn't.

Comment: Sure @Rob - I get that. I suppose in the world of academic view points it makes sense to explore what practitioners would not do. And then explain how to do what practitioners everywhere don't do - rather than say it doesn't make sense to do that in the first place. In retrospect I guess I don't really get that is just a syntax error. It is a train of thought error in my view. Hence our difference of opinion.